# Redirect and rewrite file to subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, subdomain

Our site have this url

```
http://mydomain.com/blog.php?id=50
```

and need redirect its by 301 to

```
http://blogs.mydomain.com/blog.php?id=50
```

must create sub domain or folder or can we do it directly .htaccess file ?

Comment: are you using wordpress? or any other CMS/Framework? only this URL needs to be redirected to all the /blog.php urls?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following in your .htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com [NC] 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^blog\.php$ http://blogs.mydomain.com/blog.php?id=%1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Nice it's worked but how we can rewrite

http://mydomain.com/blog.php?id=50
to
http://blogs.mydomain.com/blog.php?id=50

Comment: meno, I don't understand your question - could you provide more details on what is not working and what you would like it to do

Comment: The code redirected well, but also need rewrite blog.php to blogs.mydomain.com